# SQL - Splitting a string into a new row

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table with with two columns as shown below:

```
A001    A1;A2;A3
B002    B1
C003    C1;C2
D004    D1;D2;D3;D4
E005    E1
```

The table has two columns, the second column has contains either a single value or multiple values as a string separated by a semicolon.

What i would like to do is for each of the rows where the value is a string with multiple values, i want to split the string and use each value to insert a new row (duplicating the value from the first column for the new row).

With the above sample data, the output would be something like this:

```
A001 A1
A001 A2
A001 A3
B002 B1
C003 C1
C003 C2
D004 D1
D004 D2
D004 D3
D004 D4
E005 E1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with src as
(
        select 'A001' col1, 'A1;A2;A3' col2 from dual union all
        select 'B002',      'B1'            from dual union all
        select 'C003',      'C1;C2'         from dual union all
        select 'D004',      'D1;D2;D3;D4'   from dual union all
        select 'E005',      'E1'            from dual
)
, explode as
(
        select  col1
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 1) as col2_1
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 2) as col2_2
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 3) as col2_3
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 4) as col2_4
        --      if there is more add more...
        from    src
)
select col1, col2_1 from explode where col2_1 is not null union all
select col1, col2_2 from explode where col2_2 is not null union all
select col1, col2_3 from explode where col2_3 is not null union all
select col1, col2_4 from explode where col2_4 is not null 
order by col1
;
```

The result:

```
/*
A001    A1
A001    A2
A001    A3
B002    B1
C003    C2
C003    C1
D004    D1
D004    D4
D004    D2
D004    D3
E005    E1
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, txt from table1
model partition by (id) dimension by (1 as n) measures (txt) (
  txt[for n from regexp_count(txt[1], '[^;]+') to 1 decrement 1] = 
  regexp_substr(txt[1], '[^;]+', 1, cv(n))
)
order by id, n
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/122f3/1)

Comment: Would you mind to comment your query ? There's plenty of components that are unfamiliar for me, like `model partition by`, `dimension by`, `measures` and `txt[...]`. And where that `cv()` comes from ?

Comment: That's [dark side of Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/sqlmodel.htm).

Comment: The dark side indeed ! From the linked guide: _The MODEL clause brings a new level of power ..._

Comment: Yes, it's dark power )))

Answer (score 1):

Heres a solution, I took some code from another website but cant remember whos and then modified it. I added some data to a temp table to show it works

```
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (COL1 NVARCHAR(10), COL2 NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE (COL1 NVARCHAR(10),COL2 NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @COL1 NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @COL2 NVARCHAR(10)

INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ( 'A001',    'A1;A2;A3')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ( 'B002',    'B1')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ( 'C003',    'C1;C2')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ( 'D004',    'D1;D2;D3;D4')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ( 'E005',    'E1')


DECLARE CURDB CURSOR FOR
SELECT  *
FROM    @DATA

OPEN CURDB

FETCH NEXT FROM CURDB
INTO @COL1, @COL2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @S varchar(max),
@Split char(1),
@X xml

SELECT @S = @COL2,
@Split = ';'

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

INSERT INTO @RESULT
SELECT @COL1,[Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)

FETCH NEXT FROM CURDB
INTO @COL1, @COL2

END 
CLOSE CURDB;
DEALLOCATE CURDB;

SELECT *
FROM @RESULT
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to transpose data from rows to columns.

In this case where you also need to split a string into different elements, I like to use a pipelined function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg AS
  2     TYPE tab_varchar2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
  3     FUNCTION split_string (p VARCHAR2) RETURN tab_varchar2 PIPELINED;
  4  END;
  5  /

Package created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg AS
  2     FUNCTION split_string (p VARCHAR2) RETURN tab_varchar2 PIPELINED IS
  3        l_tail    LONG := p;
  4        l_separator NUMBER;
  5     BEGIN
  6        WHILE l_tail IS NOT NULL LOOP
  7           l_separator := instr(l_tail, ';');
  8           IF l_separator <= 0 THEN
  9              PIPE ROW (l_tail);
 10              l_tail := '';
 11           ELSE
 12              PIPE ROW (substr(l_tail, 1, l_separator - 1));
 13              l_tail := substr(l_tail, l_separator + 1);
 14           END IF;
 15        END LOOP;
 16        RETURN;
 17     END split_string;
 18  END;
 19  /

Package body created
```

You query the data with a lateral join:

```
SQL> WITH data AS (
  2     SELECT 'A001' ID, 'A1;A2;A3' txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 'B002' ID, 'B1' txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 'C003' ID, 'C1;C2' txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 'D004' ID, 'D1;D2;D3;D4' txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 'E005' ID, 'E1' txt FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT d.id, COLUMN_VALUE
  9    FROM data d
 10         CROSS JOIN TABLE(pkg.split_string(d.txt));

ID           COLUMN_VALUE
------------ --------------------------------------------------
A001         A1
A001         A2
A001         A3
B002         B1
C003         C1
C003         C2
D004         D1
D004         D2
D004         D3
D004         D4
E005         E1
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use the below query to convert comma separated values in rows

```
SELECT trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) COLUMNS
from t t, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(valuestring,':','</e><e>')||  
'</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x   );
```